# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::storagePath() in feature test

Tags: testing, laravel-10

I'm trying to load some images in my feature test with Laravlel 10:

```
class MyTest extends TestCase

    private string $path;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->path = storage_path('image.jpeg');
    }
}
```

But I get this error message `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::storagePath()`

Feature tests are supposed to load the framework, so this should work. I don't understand, did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It turns out the issue is from the `setUp()` method. It works when I called the parents `setUp()` method:

```
class MyTest extends TestCase

    private string $path;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->path = storage_path('image.jpeg');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, as you can see, I initially put that in my example. It allows you to set up the necessary environment and dependencies for your tests and bootstraps the Laravel application.

Comment: You are right I didn't notice. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use the `storagePath()` method provided by the Storage facade instead.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    private string $path;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->path = Storage::path('image.jpeg');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the facade but another exception is thrown: `A facade root has not been set.`

Comment: Thanks bro. I think it has with the current project. It's something I changed or a package I installed. When I tried a new project, everything works perfectly